# Typed Dataset not using TypedTableBase in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm migrating our DAL class library to .NET 4 (from .NET 3.5). We're using typed datasets quite often, and we often iterate over tables:

```
foreach(var row in ds.MyTable) var tmp = row.ID;
```

This does not work anymore, as the designer changes the dataset's code so that tables do not derive from `TypedTableBase<T>` anymore, but from `DataTable` (and implement the non-generic `IEnumerable`). That's what the diff shows. Therefore, the row is of type `object` at compile-time.

Does anybody know if this is the usual behavior? At the moment, I'm doing it the way shown below, but I hope there's a more elegant solution:

```
foreach(var row in ds.MyTable.Cast<MyDs.MyRow>()) var tmp = row.ID;
```

Comment: This was is a reported bug for happening from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.5 as well: [BUG-733077](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733077/msdatasetgenerator-does-not-generate-typedtablebase-t-derived-classes-when-converting-project-from-dotnet-4-0-to-dotnet-4-5).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just ran into this today and was able to correct it by doing the following:

Select the xsd files in the solution explorer and click "Run Custom Tool". The designer files will be regenerated using TypedTableBase instead of DataTable and IEnumerable.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!  You made my day with this answer.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is mostly complete, but will not fully resolve the issue.
Here's a reproduction of my [question and answer on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23661756/1366033).

#### The Problem:

In short, the problem occurs when the `MSDataSetGenerator` tool runs, but the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly has not yet been loaded into the current Visual Studio process.

#### The Solution:

One way to load the assembly is just to open any XSD file and *THEN* re-generate the designer code.

The following steps should generate the appropriate designer file:

1. Open any XSD file to the designer view (this loads DataSetExtensions.dll)
2. Right Click on the XSD and Select `Run Custom Tool`

**Here's a full [step by step walkthrough of the issue and solution with pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToLUk.jpg)**

#### Other Instances:

This problem has also been reported to Microsoft in the following bug tickets:

- [#668724 - MSDataSetGenerator generates incorrect output sometimes](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668724/)
- [#733077 - MSDataSetGenerator does not generate TypedTableBase derived classes](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733077/)

Comment: We just ran into this problem.  Thank you for pointing out the DataSetExtensions.dll has to be loaded for the custom tool the generate the correct code!

Answer (score 2):

All this is correct but in my case I had to support source code which needs to run with .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0. My objective was to change as little code as possible.

My solution was to create a **partial extension under .Net 4.0** and bind it to the 4.0 application. This looks like:

```
namespace NamespaceOfMyDataSet
{
    public partial class MyDataSet : global::System.Data.DataSet 
    {
        public partial class MyTypedTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<MyTypedTableRow> 
        {
            public System.Data.DataRowCollection GetRows()
            {
                return this.Rows;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works like a charme!!!