# xs:date values and strongly typed Datasets

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an xsd that I has been run through the MSDataSetGenerator in Visual Studio.

My date columns in the xsd are defined as xs:date (example below):

```
<xs:element name="DateDeath" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1"/>
```

I write the data into the row of my strongly typed dataset class like this:

```
myRow["DateDeath"] = "1933-01-01"
```

When I call WriteXml() on the dataset to generate the xml file, the xml file has DateTime values:

```
<DateDeath>1933-01-01T00:00:00-05:00</DateDeath>
```

The problem I am having is that when I load the created xml file and try to validate it, I get errors that complain that the date is not valid. If I manually remove the time related stuff (the T and everything after it) the errors go away.

How can I get the strongly typed dataset to write the xml so that it can be validated against the xsd (i.e. discard the time and timezone information)?

**EDIT**

I am using code similar to the following to test my xml against the xsd:

```
XmlSchema xmlSchema = this.GetXmlSchema(xsdFile);
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();           
settings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings))
{               
    while (reader.Read()) ;
}
```

Comment: Can you give steps to reproduce the problem?  I just tried to reproduce it manually by creating my own strongly typed dataset from scratch, and serializing/deserializing dates worked correctly.

Comment: What .net objects are you using? What does created from scratch mean too please?

Comment: In .Net 3.5/VS 2008, I did "Add" -> "New Item" -> "DataSet", then created a dataset with one table called "People" having one column called "DeathDate" of type DateTime.  In the .xsd I see the following line: `<xs:element name="DateDeath" msdata:DateTimeMode="Utc" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="DateDeath" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="DateDeath" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnDateDeath" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="DateDeathColumn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />`.  What .Net objects are you using?

Comment: I'm using a third party xsd that appears to be some sort of microsoft xsd. Have a look for yourself: https://www.shpdata.com/xsd/CAHPSHospice.xsd. Drag that into Visual Studio and you should get the designer but notice the type="xs:date". I have VS 2010 and VS 2013 and cannot see how they got those in there via the tools. There are other things in there too that make me think this thing has been edited in multiple tools. I have Eclipse data tools and they don't create xsd files like this. Notice the msdata xmlns.

Comment: And when you call WriteXml() on the DataSet it doesn't include the time portion?

Comment: I just tried: 1) Download CAHPSHospice.xsd into my project directory. 2) Add via "Add" -> "Existing Item..." -> pick the XSD file.  This defines a class `SHP_CAHPS_HOSPICE_DATA`.  3) In test code, add a row, and set "DeathDate" as you did.  4) call `WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)`, write to a string.  The date looks like `<DateDeath>1933-01-01T00:00:00-05:00</DateDeath>`.  5) Create a second dataset, read the XML.  Everything reads in OK.

Comment: Could it be related to this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469115/typed-dataset-not-using-typedtablebase-in-net-4/5172739

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to validate the xml file that was generated by the WriteXml method of the typed dataset against the xsd file and it is throwing errors because the xsd file says xs:date and an xs:date must not have the time portion. The annoying part is I am using the xml classes from the .net framework to do it. This is all Microsoft stuff (and apparently partially the third party xsd).

Comment: Can you update your question to show how to reproduce the exception, given "CAHPSHospice.xsd"?  So far, I can't make it happen, but probably I don't understand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I've updated the question with code that demonstrates my routine that I use to validate the xml against the xsd.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up writing code to manipulate the final xml document values to be what I want before I write it to disk.