# LINQ to DataSet with strongly typed data after migration from .NET 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-dataset

I'm in the progress of migrating our projects from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0.
Previously I used to be able to use statements on typed datasets such as:

```
dr = myDataSet.SomeTable.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.IdSome = targetId)
```

This however no longer works.
I've already tried adding the reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and modify the code to use `.AsEnumerable()` - however, this only yields a `DataRow`, not a `SomeRow` (as would be contained within the `SomeTable`)

```
dr = myDataSet.SomeTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.IdSome = targetId)
```

The resulting error is `'IdSome' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataRow'` - some other statements fail with an `Overload resolution failed` due to the same reason.

How can I retain the type safe, non-magic string code in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Do you use a dataset to access a database or some xml?

Comment: Database - but the filter might happen on the client side (architecture: windows forms client, remoting, ADO.NET data adapter. Not going to change soon, so DataSets are going to stick around for a while). I.e. I can't just use LINQ to XML.

Comment: Have you both referenced the appropriate assembly and imported the appropriate namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the datasets were messed up during the conversion. After regenerating them (opening one in designer, "Run Custom Tool" on all datasets) fixed the inheritance.

See also: [Typed Dataset not using TypedTableBase in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469115/typed-dataset-not-using-typedtablebase-in-net-4)

Comment: Still I'd recommend going for Entity Framework and Linq2Entities... if this just a migration this is ok but if you develop new projects look into it for sure. It's a lot easier to handle in the long run.

Comment: Don't worry, we're already using EF in newer projects. But I have to be honest, the out-of-the-box change tracking, easy binding etc. with ADO.NET is still very neat. It's not such a bad technology as it may seem.

Comment: That I do not doubt... I worked with both. The newer technologies are just more flexible in most cases but that also depends on your requirements

Comment: I'd accept your own answer so that the other users can see that you solved the issue yourself

Comment: I can only do that in two days :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working for you but this is working for me:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ds As New DataSet1

    ds.SomeTable.AddSomeTableRow("SomeDescription")
    ds.AcceptChanges()

    Dim dr As DataSet1.SomeTableRow = ds.SomeTable.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Id = 1)

    Console.WriteLine(dr.Id)
    Console.WriteLine(dr.Description)

End Sub
```

Comment: i have references to System.Core; System.Data; System.Data.DataSetExtensions... and i think thats all you need

Comment: you may have the problem that you use older versions of these... then you should have a warning in your error list though

Comment: btw you can use client side filtering with entity framework too... linq 2 entities takes your queries and produces sql statements and maps the result to objects you can then present... it's a more state of the art approach and easy to implement

Comment: We're already in the progress of developing a new architecture for that project but the existing codebase won't be migrated just to get it on a new architecture. It's quite a large code base (long running project). Refactoring it to a new architecture is too much of a risk - new stuff will use the new architecture.

Comment: @urbanhusky also look into the repository pattern... you can encapsulate the data access and migrations (even in large projects) to new technologies is easier